# Merge two hashes with alternation in Ruby (2.x.x)

Tags: ruby, hash, alternate

I have two hashes:

```
h1 = {'a' => 33, 'b' => 4, 'c' => 6}
h2 = {'d' => 10, 'e' => 1, 'f' => 12}
```

Now they should be merged into one, with alternation, so the final hash should be like:

```
{'a' => 33, 'd' => 10, 'b' => 4, 'e' = 1, 'c' => 6, 'f' => 12}
```

What's the best way to do that. Probably a single liner?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the logic of ordering ?

Comment: Logic is: first from first hash, then, first from second hash; then second from first hash, second from second hash. And so on, just one by one in the order they already are in h1 and h2

Comment: I think @ArupRakshit meant why do they need to be in a specific order, since you can access anything by key without knowing what position it's in.

Comment: @DylanMarkow Yes. That's my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my try

```
Hash[*[h1.to_a, h2.to_a].transpose.flatten]
# => {"a"=>33, "d"=>10, "b"=>4, "e"=>1, "c"=>6, "f"=>12}
# or
Hash[*h1.to_a.zip(h2.to_a).flatten]
# => {"a"=>33, "d"=>10, "b"=>4, "e"=>1, "c"=>6, "f"=>12}
```

Even with *more STARS*. :-)

```
Hash[*[*h1, *h2].transpose.flatten]
# => {"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d", "e"=>"f", 33=>4, 6=>10, 1=>12}
```

Answer (score 3):

No stars!

```
h1 = {'a' => 33, 'b' => 4, 'c' => 6}
h2 = {'d' => 10, 'e' => 1, 'f' => 12}

h1.to_a.zip(h2.to_a).flatten(1).to_h
  #=> {"a"=>33, "d"=>10, "b"=>4, "e"=>1, "c"=>6, "f"=>12}
```

For Ruby versions < 2.0:

```
Hash[h1.to_a.zip(h2.to_a).flatten(1)]
```

Note [Array#transpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) and [Enumerable#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) are always interchangeable when manipulating arrays.

For Ruby versions < 1.9, the ordering of key/value pairs in hashes was not specified.  For those versions, the closest you could come to answering your question would be to provide a desired ordering of keys:

```
keys_in_order = ['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'f']
```

retrieve the associated values:

```
values = h1.merge(h2).values_at(*keys_in_order)
  #=> [33, 10, 4, 1, 6, 12]
```

and pair these with `zip`:

```
keys_in_order.zip(values)
  #=> [["a", 33], ["d", 10], ["b", 4], ["e", 1], ["c", 6], ["f", 12]]
```

Comment: `flatten` takes argument..I forgot :-( Thanks for helping to remember it.